# GCM Notifications in background IOS / php Server

Tags: ios, swift, background, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

It's been a week since I have tried to implement GCM notifications on my iOS app. Foreground notifications are working but not background.
Here is my code from appdelegate and my server :

```
    @UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GGLInstanceIDDelegate, GCMReceiverDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
let constants = Constants()

var connectedToGCM = false
var subscribedToTopic = false
var gcmSenderID: String?
var registrationToken: String?
var registrationOptions = [String: AnyObject]()
var notificationWasReceivedInForeground = true

let registrationKey = "onRegistrationCompleted"
let messageKey = "onMessageReceived"
let subscriptionTopic = "/topics/global"

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    // Google Maps 

    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("apiKey")

    // Initial View Controller

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navConFirst")

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if defaults.boolForKey(constants.userIsConnected) {
        initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navConConnection")
    }


    // Google Cloud Messaging

    var configureError:NSError?
    GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
    assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")
    gcmSenderID = GGLContext.sharedInstance().configuration.gcmSenderID

    let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
    UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    let gcmConfig = GCMConfig.defaultConfig()
    gcmConfig.receiverDelegate = self
    GCMService.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(gcmConfig)

    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}

func subscribeToTopic() {
    // If the app has a registration token and is connected to GCM, proceed to subscribe to the
    // topic
    if(registrationToken != nil && connectedToGCM) {
        GCMPubSub.sharedInstance().subscribeWithToken(self.registrationToken, topic: subscriptionTopic,
            options: nil, handler: {(NSError error) -> Void in
                if (error != nil) {
                    // Treat the "already subscribed" error more gently
                    if error.code == 3001 {
                        print("Already subscribed to \(self.subscriptionTopic)")
                    } else {
                        print("Subscription failed: \(error.localizedDescription)");
                    }
                } else {
                    self.subscribedToTopic = true;
                    NSLog("Subscribed to \(self.subscriptionTopic)");
                }
        })
    }
}

// [START connect_gcm_service]
func applicationDidBecomeActive( application: UIApplication) {
    // Connect to the GCM server to receive non-APNS notifications
    GCMService.sharedInstance().connectWithHandler({
        (NSError error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print("Could not connect to GCM: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            self.connectedToGCM = true
            print("Connected to GCM")
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            self.subscribeToTopic()
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }
    })
}
// [END connect_gcm_service]

// [START disconnect_gcm_service]
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    GCMService.sharedInstance().disconnect()
    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    self.connectedToGCM = false
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
}
// [END disconnect_gcm_service]

// [START receive_apns_token]
func application( application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData ) {

    // [END receive_apns_token]
    // [START get_gcm_reg_token]
    // Create a config and set a delegate that implements the GGLInstaceIDDelegate protocol.

    let instanceIDConfig = GGLInstanceIDConfig.defaultConfig()
    instanceIDConfig.delegate = self

    // Start the GGLInstanceID shared instance with that config and request a registration
    // token to enable reception of notifications
    GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(instanceIDConfig)
    registrationOptions = [kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,
        kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:true]
    GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().tokenWithAuthorizedEntity(gcmSenderID,
        scope: kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM, options: registrationOptions, handler: registrationHandler)
    // [END get_gcm_reg_token]
}

// [START receive_apns_token_error]
func application( application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError
    error: NSError ) {
        print("Registration for remote notification failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        // [END receive_apns_token_error]
        let userInfo = ["error": error.localizedDescription]
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
            registrationKey, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
}

// [START ack_message_reception]
func application( application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        print("Notification received: \(userInfo)")
        // This works only if the app started the GCM service
        GCMService.sharedInstance().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo);
        // Handle the received message
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(messageKey, object: nil,
            userInfo: userInfo)
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
}

func application( application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler handler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        print("Notification received: \(userInfo)")
        // This works only if the app started the GCM service
        GCMService.sharedInstance().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo);
        // Handle the received message
        // Invoke the completion handler passing the appropriate UIBackgroundFetchResult value
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(messageKey, object: nil,
            userInfo: userInfo)
        handler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NoData);
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
}
// [END ack_message_reception]

func registrationHandler(registrationToken: String!, error: NSError!) {
    if (registrationToken != nil) {
        self.registrationToken = registrationToken
        print("Registration Token: \(registrationToken)")
        self.subscribeToTopic()
        let userInfo = ["registrationToken": registrationToken]
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
            self.registrationKey, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
    } else {
        print("Registration to GCM failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        let userInfo = ["error": error.localizedDescription]
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
            self.registrationKey, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
    }
}

// [START on_token_refresh]
func onTokenRefresh() {
    // A rotation of the registration tokens is happening, so the app needs to request a new token.
    print("The GCM registration token needs to be changed.")
    GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().tokenWithAuthorizedEntity(gcmSenderID,
        scope: kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM, options: registrationOptions, handler: registrationHandler)
}
// [END on_token_refresh]

// [START upstream_callbacks]
func willSendDataMessageWithID(messageID: String!, error: NSError!) {
    if (error != nil) {
        // Failed to send the message.
    } else {
        // Will send message, you can save the messageID to track the message
    }
}

func didSendDataMessageWithID(messageID: String!) {
    // Did successfully send message identified by messageID
}
// [END upstream_callbacks]

func didDeleteMessagesOnServer() {
    // Some messages sent to this device were deleted on the GCM server before reception, likely
    // because the TTL expired. The client should notify the app server of this, so that the app
    // server can resend those messages.
}
func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}


func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}
```

}

for the server :

```
  $regId = "myID";
    $message = "message";

    $data = array( 'price' => $message, 'sound' => 'default', 'body' => 'helloworld', 'title' => 'default', 'badge' => 12);

    $ids = array( $regId);

sendGoogleCloudMessage(  $data, $ids );

function sendGoogleCloudMessage( $data, $ids )
{ $apiKey = apiKey;

    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

  $post = array(
                'to' => "myID",
                'data' => $data,
                'priority' => "high",
    );

    $headers = array(
                    'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
                    'Content-Type: application/json'
                );

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $post ) );

    $result = curl_exec( $ch );

    if ( curl_errno( $ch ) )
    {
        echo 'GCM error: ' . curl_error( $ch );
    }

    curl_close( $ch );

    echo $result;
}
```

**Here is the thing : if I add content_availble  or if I change "data" to "notification" like I read here, the notifications don't work anymore and I get the error "not registered"**

If someone sees what is wrong I would be really gratefull !

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems my certificates weren't valid. I had to download this certificate and install it

[new WWDR Certificate that expires in 2023](https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer)